# Set page in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I've got the following code to change the page of the Jqgrid.

```
function setPage() {
    $('#editGrid').setGridParam({ page: 10 }).trigger('reloadGrid');
    alert("Success");
}
```

I get the success message but the page wont change. Currently I run the function in the loadcomplete section of the grid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just for the record. I've also tried to set the datatype to json because I use loadonce: true.

$("#editGrid").setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:10}).trigger('reloadGrid');

Comment: For everyone who is wondering; the way to do this seems to be the following:

    $("#editGrid").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 10}]);

I'm still struggeling to make this work on load, but if I try to put it in onSelectRow etc. it works just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The .trigger('reloadGrid') will reload the grid to page 1. So you did setGridParam({page:10}) but then right after .trigger('reloadGrid') refreshed the grid to page 1.

To set the grid to page 10 do this:

```
$("#editGrid").trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:10}]);
```

Comment: is it possible to set the page number dynamically? ie I want the number 10 in $("#editGrid").trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:10}]); to be dynamic and it should increment by 1.

Comment: @SK11 use a JS variable instead of the fixed number i.e. $('#editGrid').trigger("reloadGrid", [{page:intPage}]);

Comment: @SK11 Sorry I didn't respond. SaschaM78 is correct. You can have a variable that keeps the current page then increase it on next page. i.e. intPage++; or intPage = intPage + 1; Then you can set the page like SaschaM78 did above.

Comment: .trigger('reloadGrid') does not reset the page to 1 for me. It stay on the same page.

Comment: Correct. This is because the value for the jqGrid Param is the current page. It uses that to reload the grid. So in the example I set {page:10}.